# Is there are way to pass karate-config.js location into Runner.runFeature() method or any plans?

Tags: karate

I am using karate to make API calls from Selenium UI tests as a data preparation step and for each call, I need to define the params map.
I also have API tests in a separate project and would be great if I can just drop the already existing config file with hundreds of endpoints already described.

Any way to achieve that? Or plans to extend Runner.runFeature() for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, don't use Selenium and use Karate for all tests. Yes there are many teams that do that.

`Runner.runFeature()` does support re-using the `karate-config.js`, refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#invoking-feature-files-using-the-java-api - maybe that is all you need to do.

Keep in mind that you can always do this in any feature file, and it will do the same thing that `karate-config.js` does !

```
* call read('classpath:karate-config.js')
```

Which means you can call any JS and "inject" all variables automatically, at any time you choose.

For completeness, the JS equivalent of the above would be:

```
var config = read('classpath:karate-config.js');
karate.set(config);
```

Comment: thanks! call read config file from feature file is more than enough for my needs